# Two threads accessing same variable lock application

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code was summed up the application, the application randomly was locked in

> while (flag)

This code, running on my machine gets caught, in another machine he finished normally

The output generated here is:

```
INIT
END
before while
before flag
after flag
```

Code:

```
package threads;

public class Run implements Runnable {

private Thread thread;
private boolean flag = true;

public void init() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.setName("MyThread");
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        int i = 0;
        while (i < 1000) {
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("before flag");
        flag = false;
        System.out.println("after flag");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        flag = false;
    }
}

public void end() {
    thread.interrupt();
    thread = null;

    System.out.println("before while");
    while (flag) {
        // try { Thread.sleep(100);} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    ;
    System.out.println("after while");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Run r = new Run();
    System.out.println("INIT");
    r.init();
    System.out.println("END");
    r.end();
}
}
```

Why when I change the value of flag the main thread does not pass through loop?

Comment: What would you want your code to do / demonstrate? Because you create a new thread in `main` (by calling `Run.init()`), it's not guaranteed that `Run.run()` finishes before you call `Run.end()`.

Comment: in this example it should end normaly, but here it's lock in while(flag). At application, run() is recording an audio and end() stop the recording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
private boolean flag = true;
```

to

```
private volatile boolean flag = true;
```

Without `volatile`, there is no guarantee the waiting thread needs to see the value get updated. [HotSpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) might even inline `while(flag)` to `while(true)` if the loop spins enough times.

See [*Memory Consistency Errors*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html).

---

Also, what you're doing is called a [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock). Normally you should use [`thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--) instead. A spinlock is wasteful of resources because the waiting thread is actually working (checking a variable) the entire time it is supposed to be waiting.

Comment: I'll try to use volatile.. Why if I have a Thread.sleep() inside loop it works?

Comment: Whether or not HotSpot inlines the loop condition depends on how many times the loop executes. If you `sleep`, it will only loop once or twice. It's just conjecture, but I've seen similar examples where HotSpot does this. In any case, you absolutely must use `volatile` or other synchronization for a variable which is shared between threads.